# Insert values in table with two excecute commands

Tags: python, mysql, insert, pymysql

trying to insert values into one MySQL table using python.
First inserting values from csvfile; with:

```
   sql = "INSERT INTO mydb.table(time,day,number)values %r" % tuple (values),)
   cursor.execute(sql)
```

then insert into the same table and same row an other value

```
sql = "INSERT INTO mydb.table(name) values(%s)"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

with this i get the inserts in two different rows…
But i need to insert it into the same row without using `sql = "INSERT INTO mydb.table(time,day,number,name)values %r" % tuple (values),)` 
Is there a way to insert values into the same row in two 'insert statements'?

Comment: The second time you should use and UPDATE instead of an INSERT. In order to do this you'll need to have a key in the table; what keys does it have? Actually, does the table have a primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERT` will always add a new row. If you want to change values in this row, you have to specify a unique identifier (key) in the `WHERE` clause to access this row and use `UPDATE` or `REPLACE` instead.

When using `REPLACE` you need to be careful if your table contains an auto_increment column, since a new value will be generated.

Comment: Now that `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` exists, `REPLACE` is virtually useless.  IODKU may "burn" and id, but won't implicitly change it.